# How to dismiss a view when leaving it with tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss

I use a tab bar controller to go from VC1 to VC2.  Doing so, VC1 stays in memory.  I manage data with VC2 and when I go back to VC1 (with tab bar controller), I reload VC1 with a function in `viewWillAppear`it works fine, but the previous version of VC1 is still visible during animation reloaded.

I have to dismiss the VC1 (from the memory) before the animation or reload process begins.
I have tried, in `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidDisappear` of VC1 these commands without success.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My guess is that the best approach is to dismiss VC1 when moving to VC2, but didn't find the way yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Obviously the views in your VC1 needs to be "refreshed" after the model change from VC2.  Would help more if you could share what kind of views you have in VC1.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, use `NotificationCenter` to add observer in VC1 and trigger from VC2 if some event happen.

Adding observer.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "updateVC1"),
                                       object:nil, queue:nil) {
                                        notification in

                                        // do something
}
```

Trigger the observer from VC2

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "updateVC1"), object: nil)
```